# sql query for fetching leaderboard from two tables

Tags: mysql

I have two MySql table user and marks

User table:

```
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| firstName | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| lastName  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| email     | varchar(55)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Marks Table

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id      | int          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| subject_id   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| score        | int          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| subject_name | varchar(225) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I want to fetch details(userid, firstName and lastName) of top 10 users with the highest marks in descending order.
Marks of the user is defined as sum of all scores a user has in different subjects.

I am really confused which join is to be used here, I am new to MySql and this query is kind of challenging for me, Hope you understood the problem.
Please let me know if you have any suggestion, Thank You

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server - choose one.

Comment: MySQL is used @SMor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the two tables together by `id=user_id`, then you group the result by `id`, sort by the total marks per `id`, then take the top 10 results.

If you wanted a result even if the `user` had no marks at all, change `JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`, this will still give you a result from the first table even if there are no results from the second.

```sql
SELECT u.id, u.firstName, u.lastName, SUM(m.score) AS TotalScore
FROM [User] AS u
JOIN Marks AS m ON m.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id, u.firstName, u.lastName
ORDER BY SUM(m.score) DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should inner join the table Marks on the id from table User with user_id from the table Marks:

```sql
SELECT user_id, firstName, lastName 
FROM User
INNER JOIN Marks
ON User.id = Marks.user_id
```

[Here is a helpful resource for SQL joins](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_join.asp)

Comment: okay, but how to sum up scores of every user .

Comment: Adding ``SUM(score)`` in the select clause should do it.